# Characterization of vectors via $\ell_p$ norms

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors

Suppose you are given all $\ell_p$ norms of a vector $v\in \mathbb R^d$.
Is it true that the set of all its $\ell_p$ norms $\{\|v\|_{p},p=1,..,\infty\}$ uniquely define the vector $v$ up to permutations of its entries?

Answer (score 3):

**Hint.**

Yes this is true up to a permutation of the absolute values of the coordinates. This is a consequence of [Newton's identities](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_identities): if you know the $\Vert \cdot \Vert_p$, you know the elementary symmetric polynomials. Hence the initial vector up to permutations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I was looking at the link you sent but is still not clear to me. Could you  please be more precise about "Hence the initial vector up to permutations."? Thanks!

Comment: how do you conclude the signs of $v$'s components using the $\ell_p$ norm alone?

Comment: I updated the answer as indeed the $\ell_p$ Involves the absolute values of the coordinates and not the coordinates themselves directly.