# Is it right to say that if two vectors, $A$ and $B$, have same $L^p$ norms, for all $p$, then $A = B$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it right to say that if two vectors, $A$ and $B$ (all elements of $A$ and $B$ are positive), have same $L^p$ norms, for all p, then $A = B$ ?. Thanks.

Comment: What do you think of the $l^p$ norms of $A$ and $-A$?

Comment: Thanks. Tryss. Let me rephrase the question, and include (A /= -B).

Comment: @rex: same issue with $(2,2,1,1,2)$ and $(-2,2,1,-1,2)$. Maybe you want to assume that $A$ and $B$ have non-negative components.

Comment: Yes, Jack D'Aurizio, thanks. My vectors have only positive elements. Let me update the question.

Comment: Then don't we have $\|(1,2)\|_p = \|(2,1)\|_p$ for all norms $\| \cdot \|_p$ on $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: [This question was also asked recently here,](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1411806/characterization-of-vectors-via-ell-p-norms/1411817) but only considering equivalence up to permutation.

Comment: Thanks. Simon S, and Chester. The answer by mathcounterexamples.net in Chester's link seems to be what I wanted to know. Thanks everyone. Have a great weekend.

Comment: (By the way, writing "$L^p$ norms" and then talking about components is confusing. The $L^p$ spaces are well defined vector spaces of functions with a specific norm. Because you are talking about components, I take it you actually mean the $\| \cdot \|_p$ norm applied to the vector spaces $\mathbb R^n$.)

Answer (score 6):

As **Crostul** and **Simon S** pointed out, there is always the possibility of a permutation of the coordinates which leaves the norm invariant.

But one can show that these are indeed the only such possibilities i.e. 
that if two increasing sequences $(a_i)_{i=1}^n, (b_i)_{i=1}^n$ with positive elements satisfy
$$\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^p=\sum_{i=1}^n b_i^p$$
for all $p$ then you must have $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$.

This can be proved by an iterated argument using the fact that for $p \to \infty$ the $p$-norm of a vector assumes the value of the maximal coordinate.
Hence we conclude that $a_n=b_n$ must hold.

Then, looking at the sequences $(a_i)_{i=1}^{n-1}$ and $(b_i)_{i=1}^{n-1}$, they must still satisfy the equation and hence we conclude $a_{n-1}=b_{n-1}$

Iterating this we obtain $a_i=b_i$ for all $i$. (Writing formally, we use mathematical induction here.)

So the possibilities of permutation mentioned above are indeed the only such possibilities.

Answer (score 4):

No. For a  vector $v=(x_1, \dots, x_n)$ the $p$-norm is $$||v||_p = \left( \sum_i |x_i|^p \right)^{\frac1p}$$
so you can see that for any permutation of indexes $\sigma \in S_n$ you have
$$||v||_p = ||(x_{\sigma(1)}, \dots, x_{\sigma(n)})||_p$$

Answer (score 0):

Take A=(1,1,2) and B=(1,2,-1) and A is not equal to B
For p=2 , N(A)=sqrt(1^2+1^2+2^2)=sqrt(6)
          N(B)=sqrt(1^2+2^2+1^2)=sqrt(6)
  i.e N(A)=N(B)
But A is not equal to B
Therefore This result is not true in general